# Liferay AJAX Request: No handler found for portlet request

Tags: ajax, liferay

Asked on this Liferay Forum [post](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/74993204)

I am trying to make an AJAX request from my Lifery portlet utilizing `<portlet:resourceURL>`.

index.jsp

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="search" id="recordId"></portlet:resourceURL>
<a href="#" onclick="ajaxCall('${search}')">CLICK ME</a>
    <script>
    var id = 100;
    function ajaxCall(ajaxUrl){
        $.ajax({
                url : ajaxUrl,
                data : {
                    id: id
                }, 
                type: 'GET',
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(data) {
                       // do stuff on success
               },
              error: function () {
                    //do stuff on error
                    console.log('Error Occurred');
                }
       });
}
    </script>
```

And my @Controller

```
@Controller
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
public class SearchController {

     @ActionMapping
        public void handleActionRequest(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)throws Exception {
            System.out.print("In the Action Mapping Handler");

            return;
        }

        @RenderMapping
        public ModelAndView handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response, ModelMap model) {
          return new ModelAndView("index", model);

        }

        @ResourceMapping(value = "search")
        @ResponseBody
        public void getPlan(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) throws PortalException, SystemException, IOException {

            System.out.println("In the search Controller");
        }
}
```

However I am getting the error and am not sure why

```
org.springframework.web.portlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler found for portlet request: mode 'view', phase 'RESOURCE_PHASE', parameters map[[empty]]
```

The Request URL:

```
http://localhost:8090/portal/web/mySite/home?p_p_id=MyApp_WAR_MyApp&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_resource_id=recordId&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&id=100
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to provide as  @ResourceMapping(value = "recordId")

Answer (score 1):

@ResourceMapping(value="recordId") would work as mentioned by Pankaj.